# Communicating from one component to another Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, masonry

I have two components a navigation component and a detail component. In my navigation component I have a few options or items the user can select. When a user selects one I am trying to update a masonry grid in the detail. I am able to update the masonry grid but I need to call a method prepended(). For example:

**Code in detail component:**

```
  import Masonry from 'masonry-layout';

  // on ngOnInit
  let grid = document.querySelector('.grid');

  let msnry = new Masonry( grid, {
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  });
```

**I need to call the following from my naviagtion component:**

```
msnry.prepended();
```

How do I call msnry.prepended() from another component? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a parent, child relation between these two components?

Comment: Both components exist inside of the detail

Comment: Try Event Emitter as mentioned in Angular Document: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Comment: I will give that a go thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If they have a parent child relationship then you can use the template reference variable technique to call a method of the child component from the parent component. For example, assume the following div is you navigation component template,

```
<div>
    <detail-component #detailComponent></detail-component>
    <button (click)="detailComponent.sayHello()"/>
</div>
```

Considering your detail component has a method named `sayHello()`. The button on the navigation component will call that method when clicked.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If they haven't parent child relationship (as you want), you must use a service: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: Thanks I will try this